# VS.NET 2012 RC Crash on Web Publish with System.UnauthorizedAccess

Tags: visual-studio, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

Every time I try to publish a MVC4 website on a Windows 2008 Server by using the Web Publish tool, VS.NET crashes with System.UnauthorizedAccess. The VS.NET exe is running with full administrator rights and the destination folder has full control rights assigned to IIS_IURS user.

On the same machine, VS.NET 2010 does the publish without crashing.

[image: Web publish settings]

[image: Error]

Comment: Report this problem to Microsoft.  Have you tried a different folder, perhaps one that isn't a restricted folder by default, for instance a user profile folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, when I installed the suggested patch at the address below, it resolved my issue.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/07/12/visual-studio-2012-rc-web-tooling-extensions-update.aspx

Background info:
This is the connect issue that is likely similar to yours:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/747721/vs-2012-crashing-when-trying-to-run-publish